# Assign a html to a variable in cakephp 1.2 beta for wkhtmltopdf

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, cakephp-1.2

when implementing a wkhtmltopdf in cakephp 1.2 beta we need to render a html or ctp file to a variable.how can we achieve it in cakephp 1.2 beta. I tried using $this->render but its showing me the html on the browser.

Comment: I have created the html as a ctp in views/element folder so how can i use it for wkhtmltopdf

Answer (score 0):

wkhtmltopdf works by visiting a URI as though it were a browser (webkit). So you need to keep what you already have that is outputting html, and make a different script that invokes wkhtmltopdf and pass it the URI of what you want converted into PDF.

Something like this will present the PDF in the browser:

```
  // Run wkhtmltopdf
  $descriptorspec = array(
    1 => array('pipe', 'w'), // stdout
    2 => array('pipe', 'w'), // stderr
  );

  $process = proc_open(
    'wkhtmltopdf --javascript-delay 500 --print-media-type '.
    'http://yourHtmlURLHere -', $descriptorspec, $pipes);

  // Read the outputs
  $pdf = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
  $errors = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);

  // Close the process
  fclose($pipes[1]);
  $return_value = proc_close($process);

  // Output the results
  if ($errors) {
    echo 'PDF generation failed: ' . $errors;
  } else {

    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($pdf));
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="test.pdf";');
    // Anti-caching headers
    header('Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
    header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s'). ' GMT');

    echo $pdf; //$pdf physically contains the PDF file's bytes, so as the headers are sent saying this is a pdf resource, the browser parses the output as a pdf file
  }
```

edit:
wkhtmltopdf has many command line parameters, you will want to check them out, but be warned, they are horribly, horribly documented. The help page is out of date and so is the online "documentation".